# Downloading large file from asp.net core web api to winforms throws json value of length is large and not supported

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, console-application, asp.net-core-webapi

While downloading large files from ASP.Net Core Web API to WinForms, JSON value of `n` length is too large and not supported.

In WinForms:

```c#
Httpcontent httpdata = new StringContent(Jsoncpnvert.Serializeobject(inputmodel),encoding.utf8));

Httpclient client = new httpclient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.add(httpdata,form);

try{
Var response = client.postasync(url,form). result;
Downloadmodel model = response.content.Readasasync<downloadmodel>(). result;

// Here 500 internal server error occurs

}

Server side :

[Httppost]
Public downloadreturnmodel download ()
{

Var httpdata = Request.form["data"];
// Do some process
Result is a downloadreturnmodel 
Return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should return a File:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] 
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}"]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string id) 
    { // Do some process
        return File(stream, "application/octet-stream"); // returns a FileStreamResult
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon tribus / Paul Michaels , thanks for the reply. While using file it throws non invocable member file cannot be used like a method error is shown.   Class reference : system.io.file

Comment: It's the File method in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.

Comment: It's working. But in client side response is not received. Client source code : var response = client.Grtasync(url).result;

Comment: Try making your method async and then: var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

Comment: Thank you simon tribus.large file is downloading.what is the maximum file size we can send like this?

Comment: I don't know about any limit. But it could be, that you have to increase the timeout on de client side.

Comment: Thank you for the response Simon tribus 